# Variable is array instead of string?

Tags: powershell

I wrote this small script and when I test `Write-Host $serial` it appears fine, but when it is running in the background `$serial` seems to contain an array.

It tries to rename computer to `C000@{SerialNumber=F7ZL3F2}` instead of just `C000F7ZL3F2`.

What should I do to just get string not this array?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'DESKTOP-*'} -Properties * | Select Name, DNSHostName | ForEach-Object {
    $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $_.dnshostname -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet
    if ($rtn -match 'True') { 
        $serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name | Select-String SerialNumber
        $serial = "C000$serial"
        // Write-Host $serial
        Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.name -NewName $serial -DomainCredential $mycreds -Force -Restart
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two mistakes to be pointed out in your code -

1. `$serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name | Select-String SerialNumber`

   The [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) cmdlet searches for text and text patterns in input strings and files. Where as the basetype output of `Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios` is `System.Management.ManagementBaseObject`

   ```
   (Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios).Gettype()
   IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
   -------- -------- ----             --------
   True     True     ManagementObject System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
   ```

   In such cases, instead of `Select-String`, you can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) to choose amongst the properties. Since, `Serial Number` is one of the properties returned by your input command.
2. `$serial = "C000$serial"`

   The output of `$serial` will be something like this:

   ```
   SerialNumber


   5CXXXXYYYXZZZ
   ```

   Again, you can call it directly by `$serial.SerialNumber`. So your overall code will be

   ```
   Import-Module ActiveDirectory

   Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'DESKTOP-*'} -Properties * | Select Name, DNSHostName | ForEach-Object {
       $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $_.dnshostname -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet

       if ($rtn -match 'True') { 
           $serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name |
                     Select-Object SerialNumber

           $serial = "C000$($serial.SerialNumber)"

           Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.name -NewName $serial -DomainCredential $mycreds -Force -Restart
       }
   }
   ```

   Or you can use `-ExpandProperty` parameter of the `Select-Object` cmdlet like

   ```
   $serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name |
             Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
   $serial = "C000$serial"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `Select-String`? I would use `Select-Object` and then `-ExpandProperty`

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like 'DESKTOP-*'} -Properties * | Select Name, DNSHostName | ForEach-Object {

  $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $_.dnshostname -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet

  if ($rtn -match 'True') { 
  $serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber

  $serial = "C000$serial"

  // Write-Host $serial

  Rename-Computer -ComputerName $_.name -NewName $serial -DomainCredential $mycreds -Force -Restart
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name |
            Select-String SerialNumber
```

to this:

```
$serial = (Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name).SerialNumber
```

or this:

```
$serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_Bios -ComputerName $_.name |
           Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
```